# How to delegate call from one contract to another contract in different blockchain

Tags: blockchain, delegatecall

My proxy contract and implementation contract are in different blockchains. Can i use delegate call?

Comment: Definitely no, blockchains don't share data with each other

Comment: This is possible but really hard, could you make this question more specific though? Like give the function you'd like to call on each chain.